# In the views are not displayed in the widget attributes field Form add to cart

Tags: views, commerce

I need to display the attributes of the widgets in the representations in the Form add to cart, at the moment I have shown only a choice of the number and Add to Cart button

Now this (is not right):
[image: Now this (is not right):]

How do I need to make it (what you need):
[image: How do I need to make it (what you need):]

In the second image I have in the base table of contents it is possible to select the field of Content: Product variations and in it there are all the necessary attributes to me colors and sizes.

In the first image I have a base table Search API prime field Commerce item: Form add to cart in does not display attributes such as color or size selection, I can not achieve that result as the second image I have of the field Content: Product variations, as it were, I did not connect the relationship, the entity does not have the right, there is a field Indexed, Commerce item and some of the fields Content.

This capability is necessary for me to make a quick order from the catalog.

Comment: I understood your requirement, but it will not understandable by all, better edit your post and ask your question clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use instead *Content: Product variations* field *Content: Rendered Node* witn selected to render custom view mode like a "Product variation".

In display custom view mode should be disable all fields, but *Add to cart form* keep enable.

Comment: Спасибо, Андрей :)